# Hazelcast executing SQL on preexisting Table / Data Structure - Java/Grails

Tags: java, sql, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hi we have an heavy connection & user rich application and are running into peak performance related issues.

To work around some issues i created an task manager like table, that stores a list of future tasks, which will be grouped, delayed and executed in the future and will be retried a few times. This worked quite well but under extreme heavy load the database itself is struggeling and the delayes sum up. Connections then just take too long.

Im planning to switch to hazelcast cacheing, which we use in most other parts, when i looked into the documentation i saw that hazelcast has some sort of SQL?

Would it be possible to just shift the whole table into that Predicate Hazelcast Cache? Everything is a Map already so it wont be that much to change.

The main reason for this would be that id like to keep such queries:

```
SELECT id, type, action, retries, params FROM delayed_tasks WHERE action_required = 1 and is_currently_running = 0 and (penalty_date IS NULL or penalty_date < NOW()) ORDER BY insert_date ASC LIMIT 1
```

So what does the Hazelcast SQL do? Im unsure about the documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/sql/get-started-sql

The table itself could also just be memory based, though be nice to serialize entries. Im just wondering if this would work outside of the database and would it do seralization.

Didn´t try for now because i dont understand hazelcasts documentation. There are just a few examples on github, but not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

"The SQL over Map" is one of the subfunctions of the SQL interface and allows you to query the IMap with SQL statements. There are other ways of querying an IMap. For example you can use

- Java API or
- Predicates API. For example see https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/query/predicate-overview

However the SQL interface is broader and offers other stuff such as

1. SQL over Map
2. SQL over Kafka
3. SQL over File System etc.

See the documentation for SQL interface for these other stuff https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/sql/get-started-sql

When you are using IMap the data is still in memory. You stated that it is okay. However if you still want to persist it to DB or any other storage you may attach a MapStore to your IMap. See documentation here for an example https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/mapstore/implement-a-mapstore

This way your IMap will also be persisted to DB. I hope this helps